# Python selenium получить "URL данных изображения" из динамического src

Tags: python, selenium

Python selenium как и src получить "URL данных изображения" но сам srс динамический

Я пытаюсь скачать изображения с сайта (http://www.captcha.ru) вот мой код

```
ele_captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='CAPTCHA2']")

img_captcha_base64 = driver.execute_async_script("""
        var ele = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1];
        ele.addEventListener('load', function fn(){
          ele.removeEventListener('load', fn, false);
          var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
          cnv.width = this.width; cnv.height = this.height;
          cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
          callback(cnv.toDataURL('image/jpg').substring(22));
        }, false);
        ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
        """, ele_captcha)
```

но img_captcha_base64 выдает ошибку time out

Мне нужно как-то с src получить URL данных изображения, но я не знаю как это сделать с помощью python selenium

Короче: мне нужно как-то скачать изоброжение (капча) но src динамический

Comment: А у тега `img` есть атрибут `src`? `ele_captcha.get_attribute('src')`?

Comment: есть, я получаю ссылку scr, но так как она динамическая я получаю совсем другое изображение, но если взять url данных изображения, то получу картинку которая мне нужна на сайте

Comment: src = http://captcha.ru/captcha2/ но если получить url данных изображения то data:image/png;base64 (продолжение ссылки)

Comment: Ну значит нет никакой ссылки на картинку - сама картинка в формате png передана как есть, но закодирована в base64

Comment: так как мне скачать тогда картинку (в моем случае капчу)?

Comment: что-то типо
ele_captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='CAPTCHA2']")
img_captcha_src = ele_captcha.get_attribute('src')

Answer (score 1):

Всё, я разобрался как мне скачать капчу, ну не скачать а сделать её скриншот, надеюсь он вам поможет как мне (бился над этим 3 дня)

```
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time

ele_captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class='styles-mobile__captchaImage--sHzh3']")
src = ele_captcha.get_attribute('src')

img_captcha = ele_captcha.screenshot_as_png

with open('captcha.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_captcha)

img = Image.open('captcha.jpg')

solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
result = solver.normal('captcha.jpg')
time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: `src = ele_captcha.get_attribute('src')` - не нужен, вы ведь не используете его, как и `img = Image.open('captcha.jpg')` - только разве чтобы проверить, что картинка валидная. Поэтому, лучше удалите эти строки. А мое решение не помогло? Там ведь тоже будет получен файл картинки, который можно прогнать через `solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)`. Добавил в свой ответ пример использования с вашим кодом. Но, вариант с скриншотом более универсальный - не зависит от способа получения картинки. Поэтому, поставил вашему ответу плюс :)

Answer (score 0):

Действия:

- Извлекаете кусок `base64` у атрибута `src` в теге `img`
- Декодируете его и получаете массив байтов файла картинки
- Записывайте байты в файл

Пример:

```
from base64 import b64decode

img_src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

src = img_src.split(',')[1]

img_data = b64decode(src)
with open('red-point.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_data)
```

На практике:

```
import time
from base64 import b64decode

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver


ele_captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class='styles-mobile__captchaImage--sHzh3']")
img_src = ele_captcha.get_attribute('src')
src = img_src.split(',')[1]

img_captcha = b64decode(src)
with open('captcha.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_captcha)

solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
result = solver.normal('captcha.jpg')
time.sleep(30)
```